# Get MAX from a GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I was practicing some SQL when this hit me. I wanted to see how many times a certain commodity came up and from there get the commodity which came up *the most*.

This shows how many times each commodity comes up:

```
mysql> SELECT commodity, COUNT(commodity) count FROM orders GROUP BY commodity ORDER BY count;
+----------------------+------------+
| commodity            |    count   |
+----------------------+------------+
| PERSIAN MELON        |          4 |
| BEANS                |          6 |
| CASABA               |         10 |
| ASPARAGUS            |         11 |
| EGGPLANT             |         12 |
| TOMATOES, CHERRY     |         16 |
| GALIA MELON          |         18 |
+-----------------------------------+
```

I'm trying to get the row with the highest but it's all wrong:

```
mysql> SELECT commodity, MAX(COUNT(commodity)) count FROM orders GROUP BY commodity ORDER BY count;
```

What's the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CAUTION: the query will not handle duplicate records having the maximum `COUNT`

```
SELECT  commodity,  COUNT(commodity) `count` 
FROM    orders 
GROUP   BY commodity
ORDER   BY `count` DESC 
LIMIT   1
```

But this will,

```
SELECT  commodity,  COUNT(commodity) `count` 
FROM    orders 
GROUP   BY commodity
HAVING  COUNT(commodity) =
(
    SELECT MAX(`COUNT`) 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  COUNT(commodity) `count` 
        FROM    orders 
        GROUP   BY commodity
    )   s
)
```

Comment: @enchance yes, the first one but the second won't. consider this record `TOMATOES, CHERRY | 18`, `GALIA MELON | 18`, `PERSIAN MELON | 10`

Comment: the first will only display `TOMATOES, CHERRY | 18` but the second one both `TOMATOES, CHERRY | 18` and `GALIA MELON | 18`

Comment: Yes, since it's using `LIMIT 1` then only the top most record gets returned. Is there some way around this without having to use subqueries?

Answer (score 3):

Try this query

```
  SELECT commodity,COUNT(commodity) AS count 
    FROM orders
GROUP BY commodity
ORDER BY count desc
   LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: `MAX(COUNT(commodity))` is not valid!

Answer (score 0):

I would write:

```
select * from (SELECT commodity, COUNT(commodity) count FROM orders GROUP BY commodity ORDER BY count desc) where rownum <2;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is fine just add desc to order by

```
SELECT commodity, COUNT(commodity) count FROM orders GROUP BY commodity ORDER BY count DESC;
```

first row will have max value and add limit to get just this one record

```
SELECT commodity, COUNT(commodity) count FROM orders GROUP BY commodity ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're doing it right. Except `ORDER BY` orders them in `ASC` order. make it descending

```
mysql> SELECT commodity, COUNT(commodity) count FROM orders GROUP BY commodity ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Comment: `MAX(COUNT(commodity))` is not valid!