# How to select MAX along with another column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

Lets say I have the table as follows

```
Name    Firm   Salary
Aron    X      100
Bill    X      200
Clint   Y      300
```

I want to find the firm with maximum number of employees and produce the result

```
Firm    Total
X       2
```

However here is my problem, The following query never works in MySQL

```
select firm,max(Number_Of_Employees) as Total from
(select firm,count(*) as Number_Of_Employees from works group by firm)
as temp;
```

Comment: Top N query was an option but I would like to use the aggregate function MAX

Comment: How about this `select firm,count(*) as Number_Of_Employees from works group by firm ORDER BY Number_Of_Employees DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: @user3041058 Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Boy, the question closers are out in full force this morning.

Comment: Query is working fine,gives correct result, tested on phpmyadmin...what is error / output shown..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get MAX from a GROUP BY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414055/get-max-from-a-group-by)